# Incorrect value while performing an arithmetic subtraction on two elements of a list

Tags: c#, list

I am performing arithmetic subtraction on the elements of a `C# list` of type double and it results in some incorrect results sometimes

For example I have three elements in the `listTempStrike` as follows

```
3.6
3.7
3.8
```

So, when I perform `listTempStrike[1] - listTempStrike[0]` it results `0.1` which is true but when I perform   `listTempStrike[2] - listTempStrike[1]` it returns `0.099999999999999645` which I feel is strange.
    **Any better solution to this?**

Comment: Welcome to the world of binary floating point numbers.

Comment: You can either use decimal type instead of double, or simply write Math.Round(listTempStrike[1] - listTempStrike[0], 1), this will round it up to the first decimal

Answer (score 2):

you will need to change the type to `decimal` instead of `float`/`double`

this should solve your issue

Comment: this one this both the values as 0.0999999645